# SqlAlchemy current db user

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the current user of the db I have. But I couldn't find a way to do that and there are no questions on stackoverflow similar to this. In postgresql there is a method `current_user`. For example I coudl just say `SELECT current_user` and I would get a table with the current user's name. Is there something similar in Sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`literal_column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column):

```
session.query(literal_column("current_user"))
```

or

```
connection.execute(select([literal_column("current_user")]))
```

Comment: Well it worked in my python class where I created my tables but when I try to do it in my unittest class I get `<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.current_user at 0x7f8c5af379d0>`. Do you have any idea why I am not getting the real name instead of the object?

Comment: @Blinxen It's difficult to give you the reason without any code. You may want to ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1):

So I found another way to get the current db user in sqlalchemy. I can just say `func.current_user()` and I will get the current db user. To use `func` I had to make an import. The import looks like this `from sqlalchemy.sql import func`. I also found out that I could just say:

```
curr_usr = self.session.query("current_user")
    for usr in curr_usr:
        user = usr[0]
```

There I also get the db user. I wrote `usr[0]` because `curr_usr` return a list with two items. I don't know why it does that but it just does and the first item of that list is the name of the db user.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `flask-login` module of Flask you could just import a function `current_user` with `from flask_login import current_user`.

Then you could just get it from the database and db model (for instance Sqlite/SqlAlchemy) if you save it in a database:

`u_id = current_user.id`

`u_email = current_user.email`

`u_name = current_user.name`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

In some use cases, one might also rely on the connection string:

```
current_user = session.bind.url.username
```